# Different WiFi modes in arduino for esp32

Tags: esp32

I've recently started playing with esp32. I was searching for various WiFi.mode() options available for esp32 but I couldn't find it anywhere. Can anyone help point out the source for that information?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code for the ESP32 Arduino SDK WiFi class is located at

https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/WiFi/src

[WiFi.h](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WiFi/src/WiFi.h) doesn't define a method for `mode()` but it does inherit from [WiFiGeneric.h](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WiFi/src/WiFiGeneric.h) which does have methods for `mode()` and `getMode()`. You can find the code for those methods in [WiFiGeneric.cpp](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WiFi/src/WiFiGeneric.cpp).

The mode is represented using type `wifi_mode_t`, which is defined in [WiFiType.h](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WiFi/src/WiFiType.h). The available options are `WIFI_MODE_OFF`, `WIFI_MODE_STA`, `WIFI_MODE_AP`, and `WIFI_MODE_APSTA`.

Answer (score 3):

There is some resonable but partial doc on the Espressif pages: [Espressif Wifi doc](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/network/esp_wifi.html)

This doc explains some of the different wifi modes of the esp32 that can be found in [WiFiType.h](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WiFi/src/WiFiType.h).

- `WIFI_MODE_NULL`  : The null mode or the `WIFI_MODE_OFF` which is the OFF mode
- `WIFI_MODE_STA`   : The Station mode, which is the standard client mode
- `WIFI_MODE_AP`    : The Access Point mode where clients can connect to the ESP32
- `WIFI_MODE_APSTA` : The hybrid mode where the ESP connect to an AP as a client and recieve connections from client as an AP.
- `WIFI_MODE_MAX`   : The MAX mode has no explaination on what it is supposed to do. But it dose not seems to be implemented anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The WiFi mode types come from an enumerated list. `WIFI_MODE_MAX` is the last entry in the list (and I guess that's why it's `MAX`). An odd convention as `WIFI_MODE_UNKNOWN` or similar would be more intuitive.